# How to populate WPF window from database

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, auto-populate

I want to auto load some data from database to populate some text boxes and combo boxes when a new window is loaded.

For example when I click a button in `window1`, window1 will show a new window `window2` and pass an `ID` to `window2` (id is required for querying database).
How can i do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a very simple example of what you can do:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btn1" Click="btn1_Click" Content="Button" Margin="10,10,361,283"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
  private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window2 win2 = new Window2(1);
            win2.Show();
        }
```

**Window2.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,170,249">
        <TextBox Name="txtBox1" Margin="18,160,-18,-173"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="txtBox2" Margin="18,119,-18,-134"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="txtBox3" Margin="18,76,-18,-93"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="txtBox4" Margin="18,36,-18,-50"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window2.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2(int Id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReadDataFromDB(Id);
        }

        public void ReadDataFromDB(int Id)
        {

            //read your data
            txtBox1.Text = "Some value 1";
            txtBox2.Text = "Some value 2";
            txtBox3.Text = "Some value 3";
            txtBox4.Text = "Some value 4";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this example... It's exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

Use [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).

Follow below tutorials..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2010/06/09/ado-net-entity-framework-4-0-loading-data-in-4-ways.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> 1)Create ui elements in the window
>
> 2)Create a model class with the required fields.
>
> 3)While clicking the
>    button in window1 pass the id to the constructor of the next window.
>
> 4).Using the id query the database based on your need.Get the results
>   and bind the fields to the ui elements values.
>
> 5).These database querying and all can be written inside your
>   constructor or window load event.

You can accomplish this using [MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level).No need to write excess code for setting the values to the ui.